# Android volume of a beep generated by ToneGenerator

Tags: android, volume, tone-generator

I am using the ToneGenarator in order to play a continuous beep.
The problem is that the volume is far too low!

We can't hear anything when the volume is lower than 8.
And with the maximum volume, it is not loud at all...

Is it a limitation of the [DTMF sound](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/ToneGenerator.html#TONE_DTMF_5) or am I doing something wrong?

Here is the code:

```
private final int TONE_TYPE = ToneGenerator.TONE_DTMF_5;
private final int STREAM = AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC;
private final int DOT_TIME = 3;

public SoundManager(Activity anActivity) {
    audio = (AudioManager) anActivity
            .getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
    generator = new ToneGenerator(STREAM,
            audio.getStreamMaxVolume(STREAM));
}

private void playBeep() {
    generator.startTone(TONE_TYPE, DOT_TIME);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found where the problem was:

`ToneGenerator` takes a volume between 0 and 100, while the stream volume is between 0 and 15.
Thus, `audio.getStreamMaxVolume(STREAM)` gives 15 out of 100, it is low...

Comment: can u get the current voume setting that the device is set?

Answer (score 2):

Use this one, For using Current System Volume.

```
ToneGenerator toneG = new ToneGenerator(AudioManager.STREAM_SYSTEM, 100);
```